Wordpress as microblog: show excerpt instead of "(no title)" in posts view
I am using WP (currently v6.5.3) for cross-posting to micro.blog/Mastodon/Bluesky (and occasionally manually posting the items to X or Threads).
As such, my posts rarely have titles, which makes it very hard to navigate the "posts" admin screen. Is there any way to show a brief excerpt instead?
(This is essentially identical to this question but that refers to a considerably older version of WP and without sufficient information to actually implement the change. I would be very happy for this to be closed as a duplicate if that post were to be updated.)

Even though the answer was written almost a decade ago, I suspect it should still hold. It is currently targetting only the edit.php admin screen. Another approach would be to automatically save the first part of the content into the empty title when the post is published

@birgire The problem is that my understanding of WP development (and PHP more generally) is sufficiently small that I don't really understand how to implement the answer there!

We can use the functions.php file in the current theme directory e.g. wp-content/themes/some-theme, as a storing place for such code snippets or create a plugin  like explained here https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/intro/. Creating a plugin is preferable, as it will not be deactivated when we change themes.
